# Create a Azure Api Connection for Cosmos db in logic app Standard

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a logic app standard in a Subscription say Subscription A and cosmos DB in Subscription B. My ask is to create an API connection from the logic app to the cosmos db.
While I am using the cosmos DB connector from the azure portal the connection is established. But in terraform not getting connectionRuntimeUrl.

After running as output getting {} in depoyement.no connectionruntimeurl is generated

Can you please help on this matter?

```
  {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "connectionName": {
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        "cosmosAccountName": {
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
                            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
                            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                            "name": "[parameters('connectionName')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "api": {
                                    "id": "[format(subscriptions/<**subscriptionID**> /providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/<**resourceLocation**>/managedApis/documentdb')]"
                                },
                                "displayName": "[parameters('cosmosAccountName')]",
                                "parameterValues": {
                                    "databaseAccount": "[parameters('cosmosAccountName')]",
                                    "accessKey": "<Cosmosdb_AccessKey>"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
            "outputs":{
        
                "connectionRuntimeurl":{
    "type":"string",
    "value":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections',parameters('connectionName')),'2016-06-01','full').properties.connectionRuntimeUrl]"
            
            },
"connectionId":{
    "type":"string",
    "value":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections',parameters('connectionName'))]"
            
            }
        
        
            }
 }
```

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same issue as [Create Azure Connection API with Connection Runtime Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830517/create-azure-connection-api-with-connection-runtime-url)? In that case you miss **"kind": "V2"**

Comment: Please, use comment section for asking a question and identifying unobvious details.